# Extract text after symbol and first non-word char in r

Tags: r, regex

How should I extract text between first @ and space? I have mentioned my code below. It extracts all the words after all @, but I just want the text first the @.

text

```
@pisa, what's up?
@italy @spain we're praying for you.
```

ideal result

```
pisa
italy
```

my code

```
regex <- "@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9])"

words <- str_extract_all(text, regex)

print(words)
```

output

```
@pisa
@italy @spain
```

Comment: Use `str_extract(text, "(?<=@)\\w+")` (extract the first mention) or `str_extract(text, "(?<=^@)\\w+")` (the mention at the start of the string).

Comment: Your title is out of sync with the expected outut, you do not want to "Extract text after symbol and first space", you want "Extract text after symbol and first non-word char".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround as regex i.e. to match the word followed by the symbol `@`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, "(?<=@)\\w+")
#[1] "pisa"  "italy"
```

It can be also

```
str_extract(text, "(?<=@)[^, ]+")
#[1] "pisa"  "italy"
```

---

Or in `base R`, using `sub`, capture the word after the `@` and in the replacement specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^@(\\w+).*", "\\1", text)
#[1] "pisa"  "italy"
```

Also, another option is `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(text, regexpr('(?<=@)\\w+', text, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "pisa"  "italy"
```

Or with `trimws`

```
trimws(text, whitespace = '@|,? .*')
#[1] "pisa"  "italy"
```

#### data

```
text <- c("@pisa, what's up?", "@italy @spain we're praying for you.")
```